# React JS-components showing [object Object] instead of JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a simple text editor with features like predictive texting, autocorrection etc. I'm trying to change the format of parts of the user's input that are within quotations but for some reason the react component keeps showing [object Object] instead of rendering the JSX element. I'm definitely doing something wrong. Any and all help is deeply appreciated

Here's the function handling this feature

```
import React from "react"

export default function HandleMonospace(ref, setText){
    let text = ref
    if(text){
        const arraytext= text.split(' ')
        let newText= arraytext.map((item)=>{
            if(/"[^"]+"/.test(item)){
                let moditem= item.split('')
                moditem.splice(0, 1)
                moditem.splice(moditem.length-1, 1)
                moditem=moditem.join('')
                return <code>{moditem}&nbsp;</code>
            }
            else{
                return `${item} `
            }
        })
        newText=newText.join('')
        setText(newText)
    }
}
```

here, ref represents `ref.current.innerHTML`

the component being rendered to, is contentEditable

for
`Today seems to be a "good" day because the sky is somewhat "clear"`

it renders
`Today seems to be a [object Object]day because the sky is somewhat [object Object]`

I've tried switching datatypes
Deferring from using state variables to store and show the input
Using textarea element

Comment: It's because the given item is array object..create a function pass the variable, call the function and log it or use debugger... You will get the reason 

Comment: What are you doing with the output of this code? Are you inserting it directly into the dom, or having react render it for you?

Comment: Having react render it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `join()` that causing the `[object Object]`.

If you wrap your `moditem` in a `<code>` block, you can't do `join()` since that will convert it to a string, resulting in the `[object Object]`.

Since React can render arrays, just remove the `join()` and render the array returned by `HandleMonospace`

---

Small demo:

- Including the fix above
- Added some color to the `<code>` block to make it more clear

```js
const Example = () => {

    function HandleMonospace(ref){
        let text = 'Today seems to be a "good" day because the sky is somewhat "clear"';
        if(text){
            const arraytext= text.split(' ')
            let newText= arraytext.map((item)=>{
                if(/"[^"]+"/.test(item)){
                    let moditem= item.split('')
                    moditem.splice(0, 1)
                    moditem.splice(moditem.length-1, 1)
                    moditem=moditem.join('')
                    return <code>{moditem}&nbsp;</code>
                }
                else{
                    return `${item} `
                }
            })
            return newText;
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <em>{HandleMonospace()}</em>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
code { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: thanks works great, i should also have just returned the newText instead of doing a bit too much with setting the state

Comment: Uhmn thats hard to say, I did it like this to create a [mre]. It really depends on your case if you should use a setState or just return the value.

Comment: setting state was making everything look more verbose when i could just return the value from the function

Answer (score 0):

The issue is newText is supposed to return an array but the else block is trying to add a space to it.

```
else {
   return `${item} ` // incorrect format 
   return item
} 
/* other code */

// join works on array, so newText should always return an array
newText = newText.join('') 
setText(newText)
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't solve the issue, the issue is react rendering a [object Object] instead of JSX